# What is the name of the group of colours resembling the shades of face powder? Powder colours?

Tags: color-theory

What is the name of the group of colours resembling the shades of face powder? Powder colours? These colours are very popular in clothes. I need to know the name of this group of colours.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe there is a *specific* name for any particular color palette or group of colors (beyond models such as RGB/CMYK) - face powder or otherwise.

Comment: Well, but how are they called? E.g. We have mint coloures because they resemble mint shades. And how about powder shades?

Comment: Any "names" would be *entirely* dependent upon *who* you ask. I wouldn't know what "mint colors" mean other than perhaps they are green. There's no industry-standard naming convention for various color groupings.

Comment: well.."skin tones" would work? No standard, but it would be pretty understandable?

Comment: Unless Jane is looking for things like "Summer, Autumn, Winter" -- which can be used in the makeup industry.

Comment: Scott, no, I'm not looking for things like 'Summer, Autumn, Winter', but thanks for trying to help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your revised question and comments I believe the term you're seeking is "Flesh tone" or "Skin tone" or could be any other similar variant such as "Flesh color" "Skin color"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! Probably, these are the words!

Comment: And how about 'powder beige', 'powder pink', etc? Do they enter this group of colours, too?

Comment: @Jane3 - No "powder <colour>" tones exist semantically... Use _skin tone_, that is the accepted term in the English language. :-)

Comment: It does exist as I have discovered eventually! Have a look at the phrase 'a powder pink retro-style polka dot shirt dress' in this Daily Mail article: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-2425503/Eva-Mendes-picture-elegance-stylish-powder-pink-polka-dot-shirt-dress.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Benteh and Ryan for the good synonyms! But the 'powder colour / tone' does exist! Yippee! This Daily Mail article contains the phrase 'a powder pink retro-style polka dot shirt dress' which gives legal semantical existence to powder colours! Have a look: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-2425503/Eva-Mendes-picture-elegance-stylish-powder-pink-polka-dot-shirt-dress.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Nude Color

Is the way that it's called in the fashion industry.

---

[image]

*Image source [tkees.com](https://tkees.com/products/foundations)*

---

[image]

[image: clinique]

[image: maybelline]